# Unable to filter SharePoint rest API according to person or group field

Tags: sharepoint-online, custom-list, sharepoint-rest-api

I have **Custom list** where I created a **person or group** field name -> **owner** now when I filter according to this field It give me following error.

> The expression "Owner/LoginName eq i:0" is not valid.

Same error is shown for field **LastName** and **FirstName**.

I hit this api's ->

1. `SharePoint Site URL/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('customlisttitle')/items?$select=ID,Owner/EMail,Owner/FirstName,Owner/LastName&$filter=Owner/LoginName eq "+encodeURI('i:0#.f|membership|spintboxtest@fluidigm.com')+"&$expand=Owner`
2. `SharePoint Site URL/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('customlisttitle')/items?$select=ID,Owner/EMail,Owner/FirstName,Owner/LastName&$expand=Owner&$filter=Owner/FirstName eq abc`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can you try the following queries?

`/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('customlisttitle')/items?$select=ID,Owner/EMail,Owner/FirstName,Owner/LastName&$filter=Owner/LoginName eq "+encodeURI('i:0#.f|membership|spintboxtest@fluidigm.com')+"&$expand=Owner/LoginName`

`/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('customlisttitle')/items?$select=ID,Owner/EMail,Owner/FirstName,Owner/LastName&$expand=Owner/FirstName &$filter=Owner/FirstName eq 'abc'`

Note the expand parameter.

Answer (score 0):

```
using react
public emailfilterItemsAsyncFilter= async () => {//6Apr
  let web = new Web(this.props.webUrl);
  var LibName="ListName";
  const headers = {
    Accept: "application/json;odata=nometadata",
    'User-Agent': "NONISV|Microsoft|6491e101-197d-4e60-8084-fc1cd2968bca/2.0",
    'X-ClientTag': "NONISV|Microsoft|6491e101-197d-4e60-8084-fc1cd2968bca/2.0"
  };
  const allItems: any[] = await web.lists.getByTitle(LibName).configure({headers}).items.select("ID","Title","Owner/EMail","Owner/FirstName").expand("Owner").filter("Owner/EMail eq 'abc@email.com'").top(5000).get();
  return allItems.length;
}
```